# iphone - stop and restore method

Tags: iphone

i'm using this function to create movement, how do i stop the movement? i want it to restore to the start point. thanks.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(shuffleOnTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) shuffleOnTimer {

    jb.center = CGPointMake(jb.center.x+pos1.x,jb.center.y+pos1.y);

    if(jb.center.x > 60 || jb.center.x < 0)
    pos1.x = -pos1.x;
    if(jb.center.y > 240 || jb.center.y < 100)
    pos1.y = -pos1.y;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point you should invalidate the timer. You'll need to store a reference to it in order to do this:

In your header file:

```
@class myClass : NSObject {
    ....
    NSTimer      *timer;
    CGPoint      originalPoint;
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint originalPoint;
```

In your implementation file:

```
self.originalPoint = jb.position;
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval…
```

as some later point:

```
[self.timer invalidate];
self.timer = nil;         //very important, to avoid dangling pointers
jb.position = self.originalPoint;
```

Comment: As he said, you'll need to store a reference to the timer.  In his example, he's made the timer a property of the current class.

Comment: now works but this only stop the animation, how do i restore it to the start position?

Comment: When you call [self.timer invalidate], you can then set jb.center to the original position. Perhaps add an additional member variable to store the original position.

Comment: what to inert in the self.originalPoint = position; 
what is the position?
btw why (readwrite, assign) in the property?

Comment: THX.
i used center instead position (jb.center), is that what you meant right?
do i need to dealloc the timer object?
why (readwrite, assign) for the timer property?
do i need to create CGPoint (like originalPoint) for each of my objects (jb2 , jb3 ...)?

Comment: timers are retained by the run loop when scheduled, so you don't have to retain it. When you invalidate it, the runloop will release it, so you nil it out there to prevent a dangling reference.

Comment: thanks!!! my last question, do i need to create CGPoint (like the originalPoint) for each of my objects (jb2 , jb3 ...) ?

Comment: You'll need to store the original location for any object whose position you want to restore when the animation finishes.

Comment: is there a way to store more then one object location in one CGPoint? (and by so not creating 50 CGPoints for 50 image objects)

Comment: no, but you could use an NSArray or NSDictionary to store your points in, using +[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:]

Comment: I think we've gotten a bit far afield from timers; you may want to post a new question.

Comment: already did, thanks a lot for your help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871068/create-a-restore-point-current-position