# need to create a restore point (to save the current image position)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how do i create a restore point (to save the current position for restarting the animation later) for the say1 object (s and also how to call it.
thanks.

```
- (void) doneThing { 

     say1.hidden = FALSE;
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
     CGPoint destination = CGPointMake(152,-20);
     say.center = destination;
     [UIView commitAnimations];     
    }
```

Comment: i clarified it in question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just store its location in an instance variable.

Comment: i created a CGPoint object 
CGPoint p1;  
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint p1;

and insert it in the function 
p1 = say1.center;

then when i wanted to restore i tried
say1.center = p1;

but it didn't work.